# Unity 2D : collision with light

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to make a game where when you touch a light you cant pass through it or you get damaged so what i really wanted to do was using hard light or creating something like hard light for a platfromer game.

Comment: What is the purpose of the question? Do you want to add a collider to your light?

Comment: That is Excatly what i want to do ; adding collider to hard light

Comment: Why not add box collider to light? Is there a problem?

Comment: It wont work Because light is baked on runtime but box collider is static but i want a way to add a collider that works just like 2D hard light

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean, what you can try to do is to use a cube or any other   object  with collider and with specific shader. If you have 2D game I recommend you to watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSDEcsVK2UY&t=27s) or learn more about [shadergraph](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJMeSkolnw4) For damage you can use the [simple health script](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dgsMgMCyUg) and [OnTriggerEnter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc9lmHjqLZc) function to reduce health.

Comment: Well thank you i have made what i was trying to do after all those weeks of tries , thank you